# Hiding an item in a sibling td with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some radio buttons in a table. I want to show/hide certain divs in a sibling td when I select certain radio buttons.

Here's the code I have:

```
$("input[type='radio'].map").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.agency-mapping').show();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.agency-new').hide();
});

$("input[type='radio'].new").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.agency-mapping').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.agency-new').show();
 });



...
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="map" value="map" checked="checked" />
            <input type="radio" class="new" value="new" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="agency-mapping">
        </div>
        <div class="agency-new" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

This works fine if I have a couple rows. But I have hundreds of rows, and the performance is really poor. I click a radio button and it takes 5-10 seconds to show/hide the div.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try use `children` instead of `find`

Comment: See if this gives any improvement. http://jsfiddle.net/vR9S3/

Comment: You might want to consider creating the whole table dynamically from JS, remembering each created row/cell/radio in an array, for a quick access (without any jQuery selectors and stuff like that).

Comment: is this the real markup or do you use any name-attributes for the buttons?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I do have name attributes for the radio buttons, but I'm not referencing them on the button click. Do you think that could be one of the problems?

Comment: @Steven: It may be, I've tried the code with 1500 button-pairs and have no issues, but when I e.g. use a name equal to the class, especially in IE I see the issue. Using `click` instead of `change` would solve it.

Comment: I've just had a look at the jquery-source, there is a special fix for change-delegation in IE, which observes the propertychange-event for e.g.  radio-buttons . This may be the problem here, because when you click one button, the propertychange-event fires for all buttons with the name equal to the name of the clicked button.

Comment: I don't notice any poor performance with 1000+ rows. http://jsfiddle.net/vM3Hy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.on()` to attach the event only on the parent element like `<tbody>` or `<table>` instead of having it on every radio button on your table. Like this:

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'input.map', function(){
    ...
});
```

Read "Direct and delegated events" [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
. Hope that helps..